# JMSSerializerBundle: handle different name for same entity property

Tags: php, symfony, jmsserializerbundle

As far as I have understood, with exclusion techniques like groups and/or versioning, it is possible to serialize or not a entity field, but what I want is set different "serialized_name".

I have an old ApiBundle that serializes entities in a third bundle, and now I need to serialize this same entities from a NewAPiBundle, but I need new names for fields without changing Entity's property names (old api should continue to operate)

Is it possible to something like this with JSMSerializer? :

```
Entity\User:
    properties:
        name:
            groups: ['user_odlapi']
        name:
            groups: ['user_newapi']
            serialized_name: 'username'
```

Or maybe, is it possible to code two different yml serialization files depending on request url/Bundle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could implments an EventSubscriberInterface as described [here in the doc](http://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer/master/event_system#register-an-event-listener-or-subscriber).

As Example:

```
use JMS\Serializer\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use JMS\Serializer\EventDispatcher\ObjectEvent;
...

class UserSerializerSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{

public static function getSubscribedEvents()
{
    return [
        [
            'event' => 'serializer.post_serialize',
            'class' => 'Entity\User',
            'method' => 'onPostSerialize',
        ],
    ];
}

public function onPostSerialize(ObjectEvent $event)
{
    $visitor = $event->getVisitor();
    $user = $event->getObject();

    $attributeName = 'name'; // default 

    if ($this->isInGroups(['user_newapi'], $event))
    {
      $attributeName = 'username';
    }

    $visitor->addData($attributeName, $user->getName());

}

private function isInGroups(array $validGroup, ObjectEvent $event)
{
    $option = $event->getContext()
            ->attributes->get('groups')
            ->filter(function ($groups) use ($validGroup) {
                return sizeof(array_intersect($groups, $validGroup))>0;
            });

    return !$option->isEmpty();

}
```

And register, as YML example:

```
acme.user_serializer_subscriber:
    class: Acme\DemoBundle\Subscriber\UserSerializerSubscriber
    tags:
        - { name: "jms_serializer.event_subscriber" }
```

Hope this help

Comment: Thans for your answer @Matteo. Your solutions seems to set 'attributeName' to 'username' if 'user_newapi' is present on the groups list. Am I right?
But what I want to do is to set attributeName to 'username' if user is requesting new api url, and set attributeName to 'user' if the user is requesting old api url (not always set attributeName to username if the an old property is now also supported by the new api).

Comment: Hi @aabilio of course, I think you can archive what  you are looking for with this method, or I misunderstand some think?

Comment: ah ok! so `$event->getContext()->attributes->get('groups')` get the groups that are set with `SerializationContext::create()->setGroups(array('learnPills'))`... I see. I thought that this sentence was taking the groups listed in the entity configuration. This way it seems that I can use this method to do what I want, but I must write a Event Subscribe for each property of each entity I want update its name..

Comment: You can handle all the property on the `User` object in the eventsubscriber I posted.  The method getSubscribedEvents listen for the `User` class object but you can remove the parameters anche all the serialized object will be passed to the method, then you can check for all the class object you need to handle.

Comment: Ok, I see, its true. In your example I can manage all User entity properties right now, and I can even remove `'class' => 'Entity\User'` from `getSubscribedEvents` to handle at `onPostSerialize` method all Entities serializations (I could know what object I'm serializating with `$obj = $event->getObject(); if ($obj instanceof A) {} elseif //...` (or with get_class())

Comment: @aabilio exactly. feel free to update my answer with your solutions or if is not so clear how to use/intercept the serialization group (is not so immediately clear)